# How to add UI button and function at 3Dobject in unity scene for ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to add UI button at 3D object in scene. Im using Hello AR scene. Based on what I understand, 3D Object drag into Hello AR Controller script (inspector). I add canvas and button as usual. but not function when I build and run.  Currently Im new in developing ARCore augmented reality application. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It might be your canvas render mode which I recommend you put on world space:

[image: Setting to change]

That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both, the UI button and the APP sample have to respond to touch input:

```
if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)) {

    // .....
}
```

and:

```
if (Session.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 
                    raycastFilter, out hit) && doPlace &&
                    !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)) {

    var modelObject = Instantiate(ModelAndroidPrefab, 
                                  hit.Pose.position, 
                                  hit.Pose.rotation);
    var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);
    modelObject.transform.LookAt(FirstPersonCamera.transform);
    modelObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 
                                                      modelObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
                                                      modelObject.transform.rotation.z);
    modelObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
    doPlace = false;
}
```

Also, I recommend you to watch [Create ARFoundation application](https://www.udemy.com/create-ar-placement-app-and-full-template-for-photo-app/) Udemy course.